# Defining the document root directory as the ROOT_PATH

Tags: php, constants, document-root

I use some constants to define paths to specific directories on a website that I'm building, like this:

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://website.com/");
define("IMAGES_DIR", ROOT_PATH . "images/");
```

and I usually use them like this:

```
echo "<img src='" . IMAGES_DIR . "some_image.jpg' />";
```

now I want to know if there is any difference between

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://website.com/");
```

and

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "/home/username/public_html/");
```

and which one of them should I use? And why?

Comment: Try to link an image with <img src="http://www.domain.com/home/username/public_html/image.jpg" /> and see if it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use the following:

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "/home/username/public_html/");
```

since it will try to load

```
http://website.com/home/username/public_html/image.png
```

which you don't really want.

Using

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://website.com/");
```

will try to fetch

```
http://website.com/image.png
```

which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

the difference is that html won't recognize full paths on images or src attributes... but you can use this

```
define ('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
define ('ROOT_PATH', "http://website.com/");
define ('INCLUDES',ROOT .'path/to/php/includes/'); //for php includes
```

Or you can use a php function to convert "ROOT_PATH" based on the getenv("SCRIPT_NAME")

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://website.com/");
```

If you use:

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "http://website.com/");
```

In client side,The image src:

```
http://website.com/some_image.jpg
```

If you use:( Just for local file system )

```
define("ROOT_PATH", "/home/username/public_html/");
```

The image src:

```
http://website.com/home/username/public_html/some_image.jpg
```