# defining root directory for CSS & images in php

Tags: php

This is my code below, i need to set a root directory for css files to access file from anywhere in application. But this is not working for getting images & css files.

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
define('RCSS', ROOT.'\css');
define('RIMAGES', ROOT.'\images');
```

And my Html Page Content is..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo RCSS.'\master.css'; ?>"
```

Comment: check the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192210/defining-the-document-root-directory-as-the-root-path

Comment: Thanks @Suyog its now working and i have a small doubt now its working with (http://)  if access from (https://) does it cause any problem????

Comment: to clear your doubt, here is another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503135/php-get-site-url-protocol-http-vs-https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way. Try to use `"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`  instead of `__DIR__`. Because you should pass web path to your html files.